# Serialization of RegExp

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

So, I was interested to find that `JSON.stringify` reduces a RegExp to an empty object-literal ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3mHrw/)):

```
JSON.stringify(/^[0-9]+$/) // "{}"
```

Is this behavior expected? I realize that a RegExp is an object with no properties to serialize. That said, dates are objects too; yet `JSON.stringify()` manages to produce a meaningful string:

```
JSON.stringify(new Date) // "2014-07-03T13:42:47.905Z"
```

I would have hoped that JSON would give RegExp the same consideration by using `RegExp.prototype.toString()`.

Comment: You should convert it to string and use `RegExp` object later for unserialization

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im I'm not really looking for a work-around. It's easy enough to manually serialize a regex.

Comment: Yeah I know. thats why I didn't answer but comment.

Comment: @canon the real problem is that regular expression objects don't have as much universality as strings, numbers, and booleans do.  JSON is a data interchange format, so it's important that JSON be usable from as many language contexts as possible. Deserializing a RegExp instance into a language with a significantly different regular expression mechanism - or no such mechanism - would be problematic.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, because there's no canonical representation for a RegExp object in JSON. Thus, it's just an empty object.

*edit* — well it's 2018 now; the answers suggesting solutions using `.toJSON()` etc are probably fine, though I'd add the method to the prototype with

```
Object.defineProperty(RegExp.prototype, "toJSON", {
  value: RegExp.prototype.toString
});
```

and so on. That ensures that the function name isn't enumerable, which makes the monkey-patch somewhat more hygienic.

Comment: I would think that since it already has a literal representation in javascript, that would translate well to JSON; I suppose not.

Comment: Yes - it's an object with no properties, and that's all JSON can see.  You could convert it to a string I guess, but then it's still not really a RegExp instance.

Comment: Clearly that's a bug. @tenbits response should be the answer.

Comment: @tgoneil it's not a "bug"; the JSON spec simply does not include regular expressions as a primitive value type. It also doesn't include dates and various other things.

Answer (score 54):

If somebody would be interested, there is a nice workaround. I don't think, that current behaviour is correct. For example, `Date` instance is not serialized to empty object like `RegExp`, though it is an `object` and also has no JSON representation.

```
RegExp.prototype.toJSON = RegExp.prototype.toString;


// sample
var foo = { rgx: /qux$/ig, date: new Date }

JSON.stringify(foo);
//> {"rgx":"/qux$/gi","date":"2014-03-21T23:11:33.749Z"}"
```

Comment: Nice, I hadn't known about [`toJSON()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JSON#toJSON()_method).

Comment: When would this not be appropriate to use?

Comment: @matthoiland, I use this always, and I don't know any practical use-case, when this can't be used or leads to an undefined behaviour. But as you can see, it extends RegExp's prototypes _though you can extend it via `Object.defineProperty` to make it not enumerable (but have you ever iterated over regexp instances?)_; and it also changes defaults tojson behaviour, so this theme can be speculative, but with my experience, I find this approach and such behaviour correct.

Comment: I think they should standartize this. It would make a lot of sense to have this as default behaviour of JSON parser/stringifier.

Comment: What about if your regexp contains forward slash? e.g. (new RegExp( "/" )).toString() returns "/\\//"

Comment: @goofballLogic, that's correct, the forward slash should be escaped. And both "/" and "\\/" for the RegExp constructor produce the same regexp pattern.

Comment: @tenbits shouldn't the serialization allow round-tripping? e.g. https://gist.github.com/goofballLogic/61e4e7df3e7671b9ff66114a32c8ad9d

Comment: @goofballLogic, you can't do this: `new RegExp(x.toString())`, as `toString` creates RegExp literal notation, it has trailing forward slash, and ends also with forward slash, optionally followed by regexp flages: `/REGEXP_STRING/FLAGS`. So `new RegExp("foo", "i").toString()` produces: "/foo/i" string. Consider my edits: https://gist.github.com/tenbits/ec7f0155b57b2d61a6cc90ef3d5f8b49

Comment: @tenbits, yeah. I'm going to avoid using this pattern because people will undoubtedly make the mistake of assuming that string to be consumable by the RegExp constructor.

Answer (score 40):

Both [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) can be customized to do custom serialization and deserialization by using the `replacer` and `reviver` arguments.

```js
const o = {
  foo: "bar",
  re: /foo/gi
};

function replacer(key, value) {
  if (value instanceof RegExp)
    return ("__REGEXP " + value.toString());
  else
    return value;
}

function reviver(key, value) {
  if (value.toString().indexOf("__REGEXP ") == 0) {
    const m = value.split("__REGEXP ")[1].match(/\/(.*)\/(.*)?/);
    return new RegExp(m[1], m[2] || "");
  } else
    return value;
}

console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o, replacer, 2), reviver));
```

You just have to come up with your own serialization format.

Comment: Nice, I feel like there could be a js library just for serializing/deserializing a regex.

Comment: doing reClone = eval(re.toString()) is a lot shorter and easier to understand (and works). I'm not saying this is how you should do it, I'm asking a question. Anyone know if the `eval` method is slower compared to the method used here?

Comment: there is npm lib that you can use   https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialize-javascript

Answer (score 7):

Here's how I solved this issue:

Serialize it as a string:

```
var pattern = /foobar/i;
var serialized = JSON.stringify(pattern.toString());
```

Then rehydrate it using another regex:

```
var fragments = serialized.match(/\/(.*?)\/([a-z]*)?$/i);
var rehydrated = new RegExp(fragments[1], fragments[2] || '');
```

Preserves the pattern and flags - hope this helps someone!

Comment: A bit more future-proof to use `[a-zA-Z]+` instead of `[gimy]?` (there are 6 flags at the current time; also there can be more than one flag... in fact I think using them all, e.g. `/x/gimsuy` is valid!)

Comment: In 2019 yes, I think some of those weren't in use at the time of my OG answer :)

Answer (score 5):

I think a good approach would be something like this:

```
function stringifyFilter(key,value) {
    if (value instanceof RegExp) {
        return value.toString();
    }

    return value;
}

var myObj = {
    text : 'Howdy ho!',
    pattern : /[a-z]+/i
}

JSON.stringify(myObj,stringifyFilter); // output: {"text":"Howdy ho!","pattern":"/[a-z]+/i"}
```

Comment: That's nice, I didn't know that the second argument of `JSON.stringify` was a filter.

Answer (score 4):

```
RegExp.prototype.toJSON = RegExp.prototype.toString;

var regexp = /^[0-9]+$/;
var foo = { rgx: regexp.source, date: new Date };
var stringified = JSON.stringify(foo);
new RegExp(JSON.parse(stringified).rgx)
```

Comment: My example is different from the one above because using mine you can serialize/deserialize using JSON.stringify/parse and get the same regex result.

Comment: You can improve this by toString the source in the toJSON method. `RegExp.prototype.toJSON = function() { return this.source.toString(); };`

Comment: You're not even using that prototype method you assigned

Comment: @HutchMoore try `JSON.stringify({ rgx: regexp });`

Comment: @Sagi you explicitly called `.source` on it, which returns a stirng. That's all I was saying