# JSON from EJS to JSON object in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I am using EJS with Node.JS, and am passing a JSON object into it, but need to have access to it as a usable object in the page. I am getting the unexpected token o error from this:

```
var initData=JSON.parse(<%-JSON.stringify(list)%>);
```

I cant figure out whats wrong here.

This is what it looks like in the file when rendered:

```
var initData=JSON.parse([{"title":"South Hills Health System - University Health Center","adr":"200 Lothrop St,15213","coords":"40.441875,-79.960813","images":[],"tags":[],"_id":"51c0e9798384f40000000017"},{"title":"Bombay Food Market","adr":"4605 Centre Avenue, Pittsburgh, PA 15213, USA","coords":null,"images":[],"tags":["indian","groceries","ethnic","store"],"_id":"51c0519e02b7cbec73000002"}]);
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

try this:

```
var initData = JSON.parse('<%-JSON.stringify(list)%>');
```

OR:

```
var initData = <%-JSON.stringify(list)%>;
```

Comment: first one worked perfectly! could you explain why the single quotes makes it work though?

Comment: @GeorgeL `JSON.parse` takes STRING as parameter and look at your output, you are passing array in `JSON.parse`. single quotes does this: `JSON.parse('[{ "title": "..." }]')` instead of this: `JSON.parse([{ "title": "..." }])`

Comment: why is initData an object instead of a string? we stringified it

Comment: @OMGPOP I wonder the same and I guess it's related to the `<%-` operator somehow. `<%=` would fail I think.

Comment: Be careful, this method does _not_ work for arbitrary objects. For example, regexes end up as empty objects. `{ a: /bcd/ }` will output `{ a: {} }`. This is because regexes have serialization issues - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075927/serialization-of-regexp. I don't know if other types have this problem.

Comment: this doesn't work if you replace "South Hills" with "South Hill's"

Comment: the first one doesn't -- the second one works fine for single quotes.