# How to use node.js variable in a function on the client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I have a rather strange problem.
On server side, I call an an ejs-page by

```
res.render('index', {varArray: JSON.parse(response)});
```

When I try to use the variable "varArray" within HTML-Code, everything works fine, e.g.:

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < varArray.length; i++) { %>
    <option value="<%= varArray[i].id %>"><%= varArray[i].name %></option>
<% } %>
```

BUT: As soon as I want to use the same variable in a function on the same page, I get an error message, that this variable is undefined.

```
<body>
<script>
function test() {
  for (var i = 0; i < varArray.length; i++) {
// do something
  }
};
</script>
```

I hope, someone can help me.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to mix client-side and server-side code. Code that runs on the client has no access to variables declared on the server.

Comment: Put it somewhere in the DOM (like a hidden input) and pull the value out at runtime.  You're trying to mix client and server runtimes.

Comment: to do client side manipulation, you should really invest some time in Vue.js, Angular, or React. These are all frameworks that will allow you to integrate JS code w/ the DOM (not the way you have it, of course).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing an array from EJS to Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38179668/passing-an-array-from-ejs-to-javascript)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't test this in ejs, but if its a JavaScript Array you could...

1. `JSON.stringify()` the variable,
2. print string to the dom
3. Assign it to a variable within the desired scope.

```js
<% for (var i = 0; i < varArray.length; i++) { %>
    <option value="<%= varArray[i].id %>"><%= varArray[i].name %></option>
<% } %>

<script>
var varArray = <%= JSON.stringify(varArray) %>;

function test() {
  for (var i = 0; i < varArray.length; i++) {
// do something
  }
};
</script>
```

If the `test()` function isn't rendered through ejs then you could assign it to the Global object *(window)* then use it anywhere after it's been defined...

```js
<% for (var i = 0; i < varArray.length; i++) { %>
    <option value="<%= varArray[i].id %>"><%= varArray[i].name %></option>
<% } %>

<script>
window.varArray = <%= JSON.stringify(varArray) %>;
</script>

<script>
function test() {
  for (var i = 0; i < varArray.length; i++) {
// do something
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: That helped me a lot ! Finally I found with your help, that I have to transfer the "varArray" as a parameter to the function. It is not globally accessible.

Comment: Great glad I could help! If this is your "accepted" remember to mark it as such at some point