# How to send the data from .ejs file to .js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

To send the data to .ejs file, we use res.render() method. Now if that .ejs file has some .js file in script tag, how can we send the same data to .js file?

```
// Server file contains
app.get('/student/data_structures/mock_test_1', (req, res) => {
   res.render('student/mock_test', { questions });
})
```

`questions` is an array of objects

```
// mock_test.ejs contains
<script src="../../static/dom.js"></script>
```

In `mock_test.ejs` file I have access to `questions`, the question is how to have access to `questions` in dom.js?

Answer (score 3):

Here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38180679/15274869

in your `mock_test.ejs`:

```
<script>
    const questions = <%- JSON.stringify(questions) %>
</script>
<script src="../../static/dom.js"></script>
```

(Ignore "Expression expected" editor errors if you get any.)

The variable `questions` holding an array is then readily available in `dom.js`.

Comment: This doesn't work! As I want to send array of objects and not some simple string!

Comment: @illla My bad. Fixed my answer.