# How to pass an array of objects from ejs file to express js file

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, javascript-objects, ejs

I am using Express.js with ejs template for my app. I have index.ejs file where I call a function getTableValue() on click of a button. This function get data from a table and save it in an array of objects name “arrs” which is declared inside this function. I want to send this “arrs” which is array of objects to my index.ejs file to insert the data in it to a MySQL table named “student” in database when user click on save. When I tried to run the code, I got an error “arrs is not defined”. How can I send arrs from ejs script to app.js.

how could I update my code with AJAX.

```
<button onclick=" getTableValue()">Get Table Value</button>
 <a href="/assessResult/<% = arrs %> " class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Save</a> 
<script> 
const arrs[]; 
function getTableValue( ){ 
var table = document.getElementById("display_excel_data"); 
var totalRows = document.getElementById("display_excel_data").rows.length; 
for (var x = 1; x < totalRows; x++) { 
const arr={}; 
arr["studentID"]=table.rows[x].cells[0].innerHTML; 
arr["studentName"]=table.rows[x].cells[1].innerHTML; 
arrs.push(arr); 
} 
} 
</script> 
app.get('/assessResult/:arrs, function(req, res){ 
var stID = req.body.studentID;
var stname=req.body.studentName; 
var sql = 'insert into Student values(?,?);'; 
con.query(sql,[stID, stname], function(err, result, fields){ 
if(err) throw err; 
res.redirect('/listcourse');
 }); 
});
```

Comment: You have to make an ajax request. Read about `fetch`

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38179668/passing-an-array-from-ejs-to-javascript

Comment: thanks for replying. I have used ajax to make it work.