# Express.js internal, where are stored the mount paths on the app object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-router

I'm facing a very specific use case, where I need to access the mount paths of various express sub apps when iterating over the app object.

Sample code :

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()

app.use("/users", new usersRouter())
app.use("/flowers", new flowersRouter())

// Later in code...
app.get("/something", (req, res, next) => checkAppObject(app, next))

function checkAppObject(app, next) {
    // Where are stored the "/users" and "/flowers" info ?
    console.log(app) 
    next()
}
```

I didn't find it anywhere

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, the express `app` object contains an internal `_router.stack` property which is populated by a collection of `Layer` objects.

When doing `app.use('/path', someFunc)`, express adds a `Layer` object and if this `someFun` is also a router (an `app` object itself), then the `layer.handle` object will also contain its own `stack` property (and so on recursively).

Hence, the only way to access the mount point is on this layer object, inside a `regexp`. One would have to serialize a regex or something (if that's even possible, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075927/serialization-of-regexp))

Provided the mount path is `"/batchs"` the value on the layer object is :

`{ /^\/batchs\/?(?=\/|$)/i fast_star: false, fast_slash: false }`

on my computer.

Hope this helps